# Getting a Canadian visa in Japan and then going to Canada via India

Tags: canada, india, international-travel, japan, study

I will be travelling to Canada and I have a Canadian visa on my Indian passport. However, I got the visa while I was in Japan (at present I'm in Japan). But I want to go to India before I go to Canada. Can I do it without causing complications, as the Canadian visa was issued by Canadian consulate in Japan? Visa type is study permit.

Comment: Why do you think there may be complications? When does your visa expire? Do you intend to return to Japan after your trip?

Comment: @Traveller I was wondering if the place of issue as mentioned on Visa holds any importance as to that`s the only place from where one can come to the country of which one holds the visa?

Comment: Have you tried asking the Canadian consulate in Japan that issued your visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canada does not care where you were before you enter Canada, as long as you have the valid visa.

Comment: I tried to make this a longer answer, but I really can't think of anything else to say.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This logically makes sense but can you reference some source - that will be quite helpful @DJClayworth

Comment: I don't think Canada has even considered that someone might ask this.